# search data in file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, wxpython

i have a file file.txt i want to search a data in a file using phone number for example if i entered 996452544 then result will be Alex 996452544 alex@gmail how to do that in python i do not know i am newbie help me.

file.txt

```
Alex 996452544 alex@gmail
Jhon 885546694 jhon@gmail
Arya 896756885 arya@gmail
```

code.py

```
def searchContact():
    number=raw_input("Enter phone number to search data : ")
    obj1=open("file.txt","r")
    re=obj1.read()
    print re
    obj1.close()

searchContact()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def searchContact():

    obj1 = open("address.txt","r")
    number = raw_input("Enter phone number to search data : ")
    for line in obj1.readlines():
          if number in line:
        print line

    obj1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this help. If yes accept and upvote

```
def searchContact():
    number=raw_input("Enter phone number to search data : ")
    obj1=open("file.txt","r")
    re=obj1.read()
    print re
    x= re.split("\n")
    matching = [s for s in x if number in s]
    print matching
    obj1.close()

searchContact()
```

Comment: its only printing number not complete line like  Alex 996452544 alex@gmail

Comment: this is the output ['Alex 996452544 alex@gmail'] if input is 996452544

Answer (score 1):

This simple code will do the work

```
def searchContact():
    number=raw_input("Enter phone number to search data : ")
    obj1=open("file.txt","r")

    for line in obj1.readlines():
        if number in line:
            print(line)

    obj1.close()
```

Comment: how to delete retrieved line @james Python

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
   for line in obj1.readlines():
          if number in line:
        print line
```